How to find: $\lim_{ (x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} (x^2+y^2)\cos\left(\frac1{x^2+y^2}\right)$
The question
I was able to find that the limit must be zero as the things inside the cos term goes to infinity and $\cos\left(\frac1{x^2+y^2}\right)$ alternate between $-1$ and $+1$ while it is multiplied by $(x^2+y^2)$ which goes to zero.
But, how do I prove it using the epsilon delta definition.
This is the book solution.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

@JoséCarlosSantos Sorry...I am new here but thanks for the info...Will use it next time

$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta_{\varepsilon} \implies x^2+y^2<\delta^2_{\varepsilon}$

$u = \frac 1 {x^2 + y^2}$ and compute $\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac {\cos(u)} u$.
